# Inputting JSON data in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, api

Currently, I'm attempting to call upon an API to run a POST, with JSON data as the body. So I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell me how I need to format the text below inside the variable `$postParams`. I'm pretty new at working with JSON so I'm having so trouble with this.

Currently, I only have the following and don't know what to do about the second line on.

```
$postParams = @{name='Example'}
```

Here's is the entire data I was hoping to add to $postParams. So if you could help me with the 2nd, 4th, and 8th that'd be awesome. Thanks!

```
{
    "name":"Example",
    "template":{"name":"Template"},
    "url":"http://localhost",
    "page":{"name":"Landing Page"},
    "smtp":{"name":"Sending Profile"},
    "launch_date":"2019-10-08T17:20:00+00:00",
    "send_by_date":null,
    "groups":[{"name":"test group"}]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#here-strings) and [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6).

[here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#here-strings):

> Quotation marks are also used to create a here-string. A here-string is a single-quoted or double-quoted string in which quotation marks are interpreted literally. A here-string can span multiple lines. All the lines in a here-string are interpreted as strings, even though they are not enclosed in quotation marks.

The resulting code:

```
# Use a PowerShell here string to take JSON as it is
$jsonString = @"
{
    "name":"Example",
    "template":{"name":"Template"},
    "url":"http://localhost",
    "page":{"name":"Landing Page"},
    "smtp":{"name":"Sending Profile"},
    "launch_date":"2019-10-08T17:20:00+00:00",
    "send_by_date":null,
    "groups":[{"name":"test group"}]
}
"@

# Pipe the string to create a new JSON object
$jsonObject = $jsonString | ConvertFrom-Json

# The resulting JSON object has properties matching the properties in the orig. JSON
$jsonObject.name
$jsonObject.url

# Nested property
$jsonObject.template.name

# Nested property in array
$jsonObject.groups[0].name
```

I've posted an online version of the above code at [tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZVFdT8IwFH3fr7gpvikweFGXmJAYfSAGSIZPhpAyrtuwa5v2TiTIb8d2HzriHpbt3PPRnqvVHo3NUIjzuQevFoHDwmOxxyBDg2DJ5DIFUkD8A2Eaz2fALeQEuQ2udlbJuGY8wIQFxwDcwyQvkEXs6YsXWiC7qVFC98fJTY4tY9lCp4ZTGuHgjEhHw6FQCReZstQ6aJ521S9cbn30wsOtgy1IdzgxNhyj3nPxRxO8lEm23lbnYeNwdN8fhf3wbjm6jcZhFIbXoX@3ydbZrDeHhi9LIZpBalSpLYvefhMJLUEFs9MqOAVsEgQ9WOQagbJuoYlB5@Y6l7ivi1WbHSZU1zqvvl2t3ZK/4VHJTzT0bFTRn7qB9146W4O2FOQ5HSfI3Kq0UdopcrRQcEqyKt0pOnguK0SZPB1U@u4RBv5eF4Bbko@duYvitvU5XFDaXdfi/2QfyY3hl6q6zLdwVcnO5x8), so you can play around with it.

If you want to update several properties of the `$jsonObject` you can do the following:

```
 $jsonObject.name = "NEW NAME"
 $jsonObject.url = "NEW URL"

 $jsonObject | ConvertTo-Json
```

[ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) will take your object and create an appropriate JSON string:

```
{
  "name": "NEW NAME",
  "template": {
    "name": "Template"
  },
  "url": "NEW URL",
  "page": {
    "name": "Landing Page"
  },
  "smtp": {
    "name": "Sending Profile"
  },
  "launch_date": "2019-10-08T17:20:00+00:00",
  "send_by_date": null,
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "test group"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you `$jsonObject` has more than two levels of depth, use the `-Depth` parameter, otherwise not all object information will be included in the JSON string.

[ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6):

> -Depth
>
> Specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation. The default value is 2.

Here is a [tio.run link](https://tio.run/##VVFNT8JAFLz3V7ws3hQoXNQmJhiDB4JAbIkHY8hSnrS43d3svopG@e24/cLSQ9OdmTdvOqvVHo1NUIjjsQNLi8BhUWBhgUGCBsGSSeUWSAHxD4RJOJ8Bt5ASpNa72Fklw0pxByPm/XjgHiZ5hixg4y@eaYHsqkIJ3YmTY34aRdRAh1qTG@HghEgH/b5QMReJstQ4aL5tT0@53BSrFwXcONiMdEsTYq0x6j0V/zLBcxknq02Zhw39wW134Hf9m2hwHQz9wPcv/eLdbLbOZrX@rvUyF6Imtkbl2rLg9bSR0BKUMDu8eQePjTyvA4tUI1DSLjQ26Nxc5xL3VbFqvcOYqlrn5bertV3yLzwo@YmGHo3KuhNHFN6RszVoc0GFpuUEibsqbZR2EylayDjFSbndTbTwVJaIMum2V863I/SK/3I52Gz8ArP7pzE7Y92NNeTyecq8s/SnvJGq0x6Pfw) to a `ConvertTo-Json` example.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it currently, but try this.

```
$postParams = @'
{
    "name":"Example",
    "template":{"name":"Template"},
    "url":"http://localhost",
    "page":{"name":"Landing Page"},
    "smtp":{"name":"Sending Profile"},
    "launch_date":"2019-10-08T17:20:00+00:00",
    "send_by_date":null,
    "groups":[{"name":"test group"}]
}
'@
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a hashtable, then convert to JSON:

```
    $Hashtable = @{
        Key1 = "Value1"
        Key2 = "Value2"
    }

    $Json = $Hashtable | ConvertTo-Json
```